# Getting error - utocreateviewport set into true but no component is designed as the initial view

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I get this error, may i know what i am missing ?

```
this application has autocreateviewport set into true but no component is designed as the initial view
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to R-Click on the View you want to display as the initial view and select `Mark as initial view`.